# Logic App Standard workflow trigger failing

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

We created a logic app standard that uses a service bus api connection. When looking in the tab "Connections" it says that the connection is in the "Connected" status.

[image]

The problem is that the trigger of the workflows fails and the Outputs json is the following:

```
{
    "statusCode": 401,
    "headers": {
        "Cache-Control": "no-store, no-cache",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "x-ms-request-id": "xxxx",
        "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
        "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
        "X-Frame-Options": "DENY",
        "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "true",
        "x-ms-apihub-obo": "true",
        "Date": "Wed, 20 Jul 2022 15:21:08 GMT",
        "Content-Length": "287",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Expires": "-1"
    },
    "body": {
        "status": 401,
        "message": "Key 'token' not found in connection profile.\r\nclientRequestId: 0b492f59-bca5-4901-8132-b0ce10416d25",
        "error": {
            "message": "Key 'token' not found in connection profile."
        },
        "source": "servicebus-xxx.azurewebsites.net"
    }
}
```

What can possibly be the issue here?

Can this possibly be due to permission restrictions?

Comment: How do you create the api connection ? is it using amanged identity ?

Comment: The logic app is system assigned and we managed to create the api connection with bicep.

Comment: If you go to the API connection, can you check it's been created correctly ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am having exactly the same issue now.

Comment: Hi @Boschy yes I was able to solve it, altough don't remember how. What's your issue? In the api connection do you have any error? Also I think service bus needs some configuration to work.

Comment: @Nmaster88, the error shows up exactly as you reported - in the output of the trigger history. Everything about the connector, the RBAC requirements on the Managed Identity, and so on all look correct. It just throws that error.

I am curious to know ... do you set MI authentication configuration on the connector itself during bicep/ARM deployment? Most of the other connector types have no authentication data configured and the authentication details are passed through from the connections.json of the logic app itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the solution for this was not within the API connection itself, but in the connections.json file of the logic app itself. No documentation anywhere describes the need for the "connectionProperties" section of the connection. I found it by reverse engineering a portal created standard logic app.

```
{
  "managedApiConnections": {
    "servicebus-central": {
      "api": {
        "id": "/subscriptions/..."
      },
      "authentication": {
          "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
      },
      "connection": {
        "id": "/subscriptions/..."
      },
      "connectionRuntimeUrl": "@appsetting('ServiceBusCentralConnectionRuntimeUrl')",
      "connectionProperties": {
        "authentication": {
            "audience": "https://servicebus.azure.net",
            "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Found a section in the doco referencing the connectionProperties object:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-managed-service-identity?tabs=standard#logic-app-resource-definition-and-connections-that-use-a-managed-identity

Logic Apps standard uses two connections, one referenced in "authentication" which links to an internal token store, then in "connectionProperties/authentication" which links to the actual target resource.